# Gear testing rig

Tags: mechanical-engineering, gears, torque, product-testing

I have two bevel small (POM) gears that I'd like to test. I'm hoping to test their strength and their maximum torque. One is 15-tooth and is around 16MM wide and the other is 45-tooth and is around 46MM wide.

Does anyone know of a good, simple way for building a rig that hold these gears (and their 6MM shafts) in place in order for the test to take place? Would it be a good idea to just use 3 timbre boards and screw them together? Something like this

[image]

where the boards are held by screws. Would this suffice?

Thanks

Comment: Do you plan on testing different sized gears or just those gears you describe? If so, you may want to consider make the lower horizontally oriented gear adjustable. Also, consider at least using a bronze bushing for your shafts. Wood may be fine for the frame, but just make sure you can assemble and drill your shaft holes precisely enough so that they are straight and co-linear. I think you're on the right track so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Torque ratings for bevel POM (also called acetal or Delrin) gears are at http://www.huco.com/products.asp?p=true&cat=285

I didn't find timbre boards on google, I assume you meant timber wood boards. I don't think it is feasible with wood boards screwed together to get the necessary accuracy to holding the center lines of the gears to each other for valid test results. A precision machined gearbox would be ideal, but the cost would probably be prohibited. For practical purposes I think it is best to go with manufacture's torque ratings.